# angular how to wait sucbribe response before for each iterate to next element

Tags: angular, foreach, subscribe

I have a pb with my for each loop.

i want to iterate on my user list and for each, i i a api call to do to get some others stats informations.  but the loop go to next before the call response of the first element.

I undestand that the for each is synchronous and not the subscribe... so How can i do this ?

here is my code source :

```
 this.users.forEach(userid => {
    this.httpClient.get(url).subscribe((res: DayStat[]) => {
      res.forEach(y => {
          // do some stuff
          console.log('log1');
      }
    });

    // do some others stuffs
    console.log('log2');
  });

  console.log ('end loop');
  // do some others stuffs;
```

log order :

```
end loop;
log1
log2
```

thanks for your help !

Comment: not clear about your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because http request is asynchronous, this solution should help

```js
async method() {
  for (const userid of this.users) {
    const res: DayStat[] = await this.httpClient.get(url).toPromise();
    res.forEach(y => {
      // do some stuff
      console.log('log1');
    });
    console.log('log2');
  }

  console.log ('end loop');
  // do some others stuffs;
}
```

Comment: wow ! thanks all for your help !  Thanks Damian, your solution is working for me ! just adding the type of result here : get<DayStats[]>.

Comment: Oh ye, sorry for that. I wrote this code on blind, but that's good you reached your goal despite this :)

Comment: I'm not fond of converting observables to promises, it loses the strength of observables.

Comment: In this case, it doesn't matter that it's observable or not, because it's completed just right after response, it's not gonna emit any new values, so it's behaves like promise

Answer (score 1):

Jeff, the http.get is asynchronous, so you don't know when it end.

When we want has a series of httpClient, usually you use forkJoin. Inside forkJoin you has all the responses, e.g.

```
const obs=[];
this.users.forEach(userid => {
    obs.push(this.httpClient.get(url))
}
//In obs we has an array of observables. when subscribe you get an array with the responses, e.g.

forkJoin(obs).susbcribe((result:any[])=>{
   result.map((res,index)=>{
      console.log(this.users[index], res)
   })
})
```

Comment: Instead of pushing the observable into an array, I would simply map the users into observables, like this: `const obs = this.users.map(userid => this.httpClient.get(url))`. Otherwise good answer.

Comment: Really, it's a better aproach

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
const requests$: Observable<DayStat[]>[] = users.forEach(user => getUserById(user.id));
zip(...requests$).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "await" as mentioned already here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48697112/1143214

Comment: It's not gonna work, because forEach is not async function so await is not allowed. It could be allowed, if you add  `async` in front of `userid` like this `async userid =>`, but still whole expression is asynchronous and `console.log('end loop');` could be executed first